# Mangeto template file can't apply it

Tags: html, magento, xhtml

Have made a template for Magento as you can see here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main_container">
<div id="top_gray"></div>
<div id="header"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?></div>
<div id="left_container"></div>
<div id="center_container"></div>
<div id="right_container"></div>
<div id="clear"</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And saved that as test.phtml and put it in /mytheme/template/page directory. I then went into the page.xml file for my theme in the app directory and made this change:

```
<!--
Default layout, loads most of the pages
-->

<default translate="label" module="page">
    <label>All Pages</label>
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/test.phtml">
```

That should apply my 'skeleton template' to the entire site including the homepage. But it doesn't. The home page is still using another template file for layout. Also if i go into the admin section and CMS, and select home page and then design, under layout the drop down list does not include mention of my test.phtml template. I have cache disabled.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to modify the local.xml file and not the page.xml ?
This works for me :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>  
    <default>       
       ...  
        <reference name="root">     
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/your-template.phtml</template>  
                <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied --> 
                <action method="setIsHandle">
                    <applied>1</applied>
                </action>      
            </action>           
        </reference>
    ...
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks but it's still using a different template. Added local.xml to my theme's layout folder. Just copied and pasted your code but changed the your-template the correct name.

Comment: I agree using local.xml is the best way to design though, more upgrade friendly and simple.

Comment: what is the path of your local.xml file ? It should be /app/design/frontend/default/your-theme/layout/local.xml

And your template file must reside in /app/design/frontend/default/your-theme/template/page/your-template.phtml